# Joining two arrays of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

EDIT: So the wonderful folks below who helped out pointed me in the right direction but I think it's actually a problem with nextjs and apollo returning data? Sorry for not being more direct!

Here's what the actual data looks like:

```
dataset1:  
Object { features: {…}, regions: {…}, ownerships: {…}, campgrounds: {…} }
​
campgrounds: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToCampgroundConnection", pageInfo: {…}, edges: (100) […] }
​
features: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToFeatureConnection", nodes: (38) […] }
​
ownerships: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToOwnershipConnection", nodes: (3) […] }
​
regions: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToRegionConnection", nodes: (7) […] }
```

and data set 2:

```
dataset2:  
 
Object { features: {…}, regions: {…}, ownerships: {…}, campgrounds: {…} }
​
campgrounds: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToCampgroundConnection", pageInfo: {…}, edges: (36) […] }
​
features: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToFeatureConnection", nodes: (38) […] }
​
ownerships: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToOwnershipConnection", nodes: (3) […] }
​
regions: Object { __typename: "RootQueryToRegionConnection", nodes: (7) […] }
```

---

I feel like there has to be a obvious answer to this, but all I get via a google search is how to merge objects, which is not waht I want. For example let's say I have (pseudocode):

```
const cats = [{
name: "Pawl",
age: 2,
},
{
name: "Siam",
age: 6,
}
]
```

and I also have:

```
const dogs = [
{
name: "Ryu",
age: "1",
},
{
name: "Ken",
age: 5,
}
]
```

How would I go about getting this result from a new variable:

```
const animals = [{
name: "Pawl",
age: 2",
},
{
name: "Siam",
age: 6,
},
{
name: "Ryu",
age: "1",
},
{
name: "Ken",
age: 5,
}
]
```

Right now, if I try const animals = {...cats, ...dogs} I just get dogs as the data, since it's unioninzing (is that the word?) them.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: So you want to have a `Object { features: {…}, regions: {…}, ownerships: {…}, campgrounds: {…} }` with the nodes merged?

Comment: Yeah, so that its one object with the 136 items instead of a object of 100 and a object of 36 :)

Comment: Please ask a new question. You've already got answers based on your original question, it's not fair to them to switch the question after they've put in the work.

Comment: Doing so right now! Thanks Heretic Monkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like this:

```js
const cats = [{
    name: "Pawl",
    age: 2,
  }, {
    name: "Siam",
    age: 6,
  }
];

const dogs = [{
    name: "Ryu",
    age: "1",
  }, {
    name: "Ken",
    age: 5,
  }
];

const result = cats.concat(dogs);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is what I thought I could do, but it actually gives a error: data.concat is not a function

Comment: Strange, it works as you can see, and I've copied the input from your question. I just added semicolons

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why its behaving like this :( . Thanks for your help though!

Comment: why the error says "data.concat" when it's supposed to be "cats.concat"?

Comment: Yeah, this should def work. In your code `data` must not be an array if you're getting that error. In your example there is no `data` variable so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Just added the code into the original post, thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `Array.prototype.concat`, if you are using ES6, you can do this with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) - just spread the 2 arrays into a new array, like this:

```js
const cats = [{
    name: "Pawl",
    age: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "Siam",
    age: 6,
  }
];

const dogs = [{
    name: "Ryu",
    age: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "Ken",
    age: 5,
  }
]

const catsAndDogs = [...cats, ...dogs];

console.dir(catsAndDogs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get a weird error though: "TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))" :(

Comment: Np. Between the error you mention here and the error below I suspect that you're not really working with arrays in your code - can you edit the question with a more specific example that replicates your issue?

Comment: Just added the code into the original post, thanks for the help :D